# How to avoid redirect after form submission if you have a URL in your form's action?

Tags: ajax, forms, redirect, submit

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form name="formi" method="post"  action="http://domain.name/folder/UserSignUp?f=111222&postMethod=HTML&m=0&j=MAS2"  style="display:none">
...
<button type="submit" class="moreinfo-send moreinfo-button" tabindex="1006">Subscribe</button>
```

In the script file I have this code segment where I submit the datas, while in a modal box I say thank you for the subscribers after they passed the validation.

```
function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'data/moreinfo.php',
                            data: $('#moreinfo-container form').serialize() + '&action=send',
                            type: 'post',
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#moreinfo-container .moreinfo-loading').fadeOut(200, function () {
                                    $('form[name=formi]').submit();
                                    $('#moreinfo-container .moreinfo-title').html('Thank you!');
                                    msg.html(data).fadeIn(200);
                                });
                            },
```

Unfortunately, after I submit the datas, I'm navigated to the domain given in the form's action. I tried to insert *return false;* in the code (first into the form tag, then into the js code) but then the datas were not inserted into the database. What do I need to do if I just want to post the data and stay on my site and give my own feedback.

I edited Eric Martin's SimpleModal Contact Form, so if more code would be necessary to solve my problem, you can check the original here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/ (Contact Form)

Answer (score 3):

Usually returning false is enough to prevent form submission, so double check your code. It should be something like this

```
$('form[name="formi"]').submit(function() {
  $.ajax(...); // do your ajax call here
  return false; // this prevent form submission
});
```

**Update**

Here is the full answer to your comment

> I tried this, but it didn't work. I need to submit the data in the succes part, no?

Maybe, it depends from your logic and your exact needs. Normally to do what you asking for I use the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which handle this kind of behavior pretty well.

From your comment I see that you're not submitting the form itself with the `$.ajax` call, but you retrieve some kind of data from that call, isn't it? Then you have two choices here:

With plain jQuery (no form plugin)

```
$('form[name="formi"]').submit(function() {
  $.ajax(...); // your existing ajax call
  // this will post the form using ajax
  $.post($(this).attr('action'), { /* pass here form data */ }, function(data) {
    // here you have server response from form submission in data
  })
  // this prevent form submission
  return false;
});
```

With form plugin it's the same, but you don't have to handle form data retrieval (the commented part above) and return false, because the plugin handle this for you. The code would be

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
  $(form[name="formi"]).ajaxForm(function() {
    // this call back is executed when the form is submitted with success
    $.ajax(...); // your existing ajax call
  }); 
});
```

That's it. Keep in mind that with the above code your existing ajax call will be executed **after** the form submission.  So if this is a problem for your needs, you should change the code above and use the alternative `ajaxForm` call which accepts an [options object](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object). So the above code could be rewritten as

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
  $(form[name="formi"]).ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() { $.ajax(...); /* your existing ajax call */},
    success: function(data) { /* handle form success here if you need that */ }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. I need to submit the data in the succes part, no? So I thought I have to be in the $.ajax(...). And this is what I tried earlier:

Instead of:
   $('form[name=formi]').submit();

I used:
    $('form[name="formi"]').submit(function() {return false;});

It seems to work great, I get the success meassage I prepared in the moreinfo.php file, however I also want to submit the form. What I don't want is to visit the URL that is in the form's action.

Comment: Thanks, Fabio, for the detailed answer. I can see that you're an expert of forms and AJAX, sthg that I can't tell of myself yet. :S I tried the thgs you suggested, but this way the commands in the ajax part are not executed. If you have a little time, plz check the original code that I linked in my question. It was a contact form and there was no URL in the form's action. The datas given in the form were processed in a .php file (which is in the ajax's url) where an email was sent. I tried to edit this to meet my needs: no email, but form action URL (to send datas to Silverpop w/ form submit).

Comment: This answer deserves to be accepted, esp. b/c of the link to jQuery Form plugin, or at least upvoted a few times with 708 views! (upvoted)